# Probability that all the balls are going to be in $1$ basket if it is known that there are at least $k$ empty baskets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There are $n$ identical balls and we need to put them inside $n$ baskets. What is the probability that all the balls are in $1$ basket if it is known that there are at least $k$ empty baskets ($0 \leq k \leq n-1$).

Because we know something before it is something to do with $P(B \mid A)$, but I am not sure how I should do this.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\textsf P(n-1\text{ empty}\mid k\text{ empty}) = \frac{\textsf P(n-1\text{ empty}\cap k\text{ empty})}{\textsf P(k\text{ empty})}=\frac{\textsf P(n-1\text{ empty})}{\textsf P(k\text{ empty})}\;.
$$

The numerator is easy; the denominator can be obtained using inclusion-exclusion.